# data-animation inside iframe doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page with data-animation which works perfectly, but when I put it inside an iframe in another page the animation doesn't work.

```
<div class="text-icon animation" data-animation="scaleOut" data-animation-delay="0.5s">
  <div class="icon-wrapper"><span><i class="icon icon-diag"></i><span class="icon-hover"></span></span>
  </div>
  <h3 class="number"><span data-to="8000" data-speed="1000">8000</span>+</h3>
  <p class="text">Computer/Tablet/Laptop
  <br>Repaired</p>
</div>

<iframe src="iiframe.html" width="100%"  id="yourIframe" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="resizeIframe('yourIframe');" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

Comment: What is the console error? If there is one... Are you using https and the iframe is http?

Comment: no there is no console error ,  iframe page is internal file you can see the code i have edited it

Comment: What is `data-animation` supposed to do?

Comment: Of course the animation isn't working. _"The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application."_ On it's own, those `data-*` tags do nothing, aside from storing a string. My guess is that you have some script on the first page that gets the string from the `data-*` attribute you have, and applies css styles accordingly.